# python -m pip <package> ERROR: unknown command <package>

Tags: python, pip

I'm trying to run a package I installed with pip from command line. ([this](https://github.com/victorskl/yawsso) one, not that it matters)

I try to run a package with either:

```
python -m pip yawsso
ERROR: unknown command "yawsso"
```

or just calling it in the command line:

```
> yawsso
zsh: command not found: yawsso
```

I then check to see if it's installed properly, and it is

```
> pip list
Package          Version
---------------- -------
pip              21.2.4
(...)
yawsso           0.7.1
> pip install yawsso
Requirement already satisfied: yawsso in /Users/<user>/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages (0.7.1)
```

What's going on?

EDIT: As I mentioned. I have already tried installing it and it says the requirement is met:

```
> python -m pip install yawsso
Requirement already satisfied: yawsso in /Users/federico.esteban/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages (0.7.1)
```

Comment: try `python -m pip install yawsso`. as the error notes, `yawsso` is not a valid subcommand for pip.

Comment: `python -m pip install yawsso` -- you left out the `install`

Comment: pip is a package manager, you have to specify commands like install, uninstall etc. If you are intending to install that package, try `python -m pip install yawsso`

Comment: I have done this and the error persists

Comment: Please provide the contents of `/Users/federico.esteban/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/yawsso`. Also, what happens if you run `python -m yawsso`?

Answer (score 2):

For Modern macos/OSX, you need to find your ~/Library/Python/$version/bin directory and add it to your $PATH.

I added this line to my .zshrc

```
export PATH=$HOME/Library/Python/3.9/bin:$PATH
```

After this my yawsso is working correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Dont leave out install , the correct command is `python -m pip install yawsso`